# Campaign tracking on Cross-Domain without redirect (no linker)

Tags: cross-domain, google-tag-manager

Lets say we have the following url:
https://www.sale.com/?utm_source=CDTest3Newsletter&utm_medium=CDTest3Email&utm_campaign=CDTest3FallSale&utm_id=CDT3ID
A user clicks on the link and surf through it and then close the session.
An hour later he/she navigates to [www.purchase.com](http://www.purchase.com) and a conversion occurs, is there a way to track and relate the conversion to the utm_id=cdt3id?
In Summary the conversion happens in the second domain and we want to relate that to the first domain marketing campaign!
Please note i know hot to enable linker while redirecting from origin domain to target domain!

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that this kind of behavior is not standard. Therefore, it will require non-standard solutions.

Having said that, your real problem is not the attribution. In the described scenario, you are likely to lose the user completely. Purchase.com will have no idea that this client is supposed to have the same id as on the previous site. The linker adds an explicit _ga query param to the url for the ga library on the purchase.com to know to use that as a user id and not to generate a new one.

If you're not able to reliably pass the client id to the checkout TLD through front-end, you have to use your backend to match the user by the BE auth/session token. Same exact logic applies if you want to pass the attribution data. You just keep it on the backend, bound to the user session token and throw it to the user's cookie on checkout, then grab it with GTM and populate it however you like. Or you can as well just conduct a BE redirect, appending both the _ga and the UTM query params to the url.

There are a bit more options if you're not using GA for your actual analysis. If you're able to match users and calculate attributions on your own either through ETL or persistent derived tables/SQL. So, basically, if you download your GA data to a third party storage like snowflake, asure or BQ and then use a BI tool on top of that. But at this point those options should be pretty apparent from the issue and possible solution described above.